# Using radioList method with ActiveField in Yii2 to provide different options per radio box

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using the [radioList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#radioList()-detail) method within the ActiveField widget and I'm trying to work out how to set different options for different radio boxes within the same list.

I have this...

```
$form->field($model, 'some_question')->inline()->radioList(
    [
        1 => Yii::t('general', 'Yes'),
        0 => Yii::t('general', 'No')
    ],
    ['itemOptions' => ['value' => 1, 'data-foo' => 'bar']]
)->label(false);
```

But whatever I set in `itemOptions` gets set on *all* radio buttons - is there a way to set different values for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callable `item` for this.

```
$form->field($model, 'some_question')->inline()->radioList(
    [
        1 => Yii::t('general', 'Yes'),
        0 => Yii::t('general', 'No')
    ],
    ['item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        switch ($value) {
            // different options per value
            case 1:
                $options = [
                    'data-foo' => 'bar'
                ];
                break;
            case 0:
                $options = [
                    'data-next' => 'smthng'
                ];
        }
        return \yii\bootstrap\Html::radio($name, $checked, array_merge($options, [
                'value' => $value,
                'label' => \yii\bootstrap\Html::encode($label),
            ]));
    }]
)->label(false);
```